# What or where is "Kehrzel"?

Tags: etymology

I am doing some genealogy work on a German family, and came across a [message board post](http://archiver.rootsweb.ancestry.com/th/read/SAUER/2010-09/1284379713) which claims a certain person to be from "Kehrzel"?

I could not determine any location in Germany named "Kehrzel", nor did I find this to be a German word.  Is this perhaps a misspelling of a German word (or a  German town), or two German words put together?

Since it is old (1800s), perhaps this term has morphed into something else?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because should be on http://genealogy.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: Hi! This question has nothing to do with German language, as it is obviously about a location. The name of this location is certainly misspelled. http://genealogy.stackexchange.com/ is the right site on the Stackexchange network for you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The current spelling is [Kerzell](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kerzell), I think, incorporated into [Eichenzell](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eichenzell) in 1972, if Wikipedia is to be believed. Good luck with your research!

Comment: According to the wiki article, however, Kerzell has been the correct spelling since at least 1303. Any other source for this?

Comment: @Hackworth: according to [this entry](http://archiver.rootsweb.ancestry.com/th/read/SAUER/2010-09/1284379713) where Wiesbaden is also misspelled it appears to be **Kerzell** as the most likely location, as it is not too far away from Wiesbaden. Good find BTW!